# scipy and preserving mat file (.mat matlab data file) structure

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, file-io, scipy

After referring to scipy and numpy docs for a day and a half, I tried doing this -

```
dt = {'names':[u'OSversInt',u'Desc',u'OSversStr',\
... u'OSname',u'platform',u'Board'],\
...'formats':['O','O','O','O','O','O']}

aa = np.array([[ np.array([[ ([[15]],[u''],[u'5.0,1'],\
... [u'Android'],[u'main'],[u'MSM8960'])]], np.dtype(dt))]]\
... ,np.dtype(object))
```

**Expected outcome:**

Expected because when I do

```
aa = scipy.io.loadmat('file.mat')
```

yields the below outcome.

```
aa = array([[ array([[ ([[15]], [], [u'5.0.1'], [u'Android'], [u'main'], [u'MSM8960'])]], 
          dtype=[('OSversInt', 'O'), ('Desc', 'O'), ('OSversStr', 'O'),
    ('OSname', 'O'), ('platform', 'O'), ('Board', 'O')])]], dtype=object)
```

**Actual outcome** -

```
array([[[[ ([[15]], [u''], [u'5.0.1'], [u'Android'], [u'main']
,[u'MSM8960'])]]]], dtype=object)
```

**How do I make my actual outcome match my expected outcome?**
This is essential to preserve the existing mat file structure.

Comment: The printing style for that 'Actual outcome' may be confusing you.  Look at `aa.item().dtype`.  `aa` is a 4d item array with dtype object.  That item itself is 2d, with a compound dtype.  The print format just doesn't show all the complex structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Octave I created a cell with a structure object:

```
octave:14> y={x}
y = 
{
  [1,1] =

    scalar structure containing the fields:

      OSversInt =  15
      Desc = 
      OSverStr = 5.0.1
      OSname = Android

}
octave:15> save stack32723802.mat -V7 y
```

In `numpy` I load it as:

```
In [376]: L=loadmat('stack32723802.mat')
In [377]: L['y']
Out[377]: 
array([[ array([[([[15.0]], [], ['5.0.1'], ['Android'])]], 
      dtype=[('OSversInt', 'O'), ('Desc', 'O'), ('OSverStr', 'O'), ('OSname', 'O')])]], 
      dtype=object)
```

That's a 2d object array (1,1), with one item, which is also 2d (1,1), with the compound dtype.

```
In [390]: y=L['y']
In [391]: y[0,0]
Out[391]: 
array([[([[15.0]], [], ['5.0.1'], ['Android'])]], 
      dtype=[('OSversInt', 'O'), ('Desc', 'O'), ('OSverStr', 'O'), ('OSname', 'O')])

In [392]: y[0,0][0,0]
Out[392]: ([[15.0]], [], ['5.0.1'], ['Android'])

In [394]: y[0,0]['OSversInt']
Out[394]: array([[array([[ 15.]])]], dtype=object)

In [395]: y[0,0]['OSname']
Out[395]: 
array([[array(['Android'], 
      dtype='<U7')]], dtype=object)
```

The 4d 'actual outcome' is the result of `np.array` producing the highest dimensional array it can.

First create the inner structured array:

```
In [405]: dt=y.item().dtype
In [406]: item=([[15.0]], [], ['5.0.1'], ['Android'])
In [407]: array1 = np.array([[item]], dtype=dt)
In [408]: array1
Out[408]: 
array([[([[15.0]], [], ['5.0.1'], ['Android'])]], 
      dtype=[('OSversInt', 'O'), ('Desc', 'O'), ('OSverStr', 'O'), ('OSname', 'O')])
```

If I just wrap it in a 2d object array, I get a 4d array:

```
In [409]: np.array([[array1]], dtype=object)
Out[409]: array([[[[([[15.0]], [], ['5.0.1'], ['Android'])]]]], dtype=object)
```

But if instead I create an empty 2d object array, and insert this inner array, I get something that matches the `loadmat` result:

```
In [410]: z=np.empty((1,1),dtype=object)
In [411]: z[0,0]=np.array([[item]], dtype=dt)
In [412]: z
Out[412]: 
array([[ array([[([[15.0]], [], ['5.0.1'], ['Android'])]], 
      dtype=[('OSversInt', 'O'), ('Desc', 'O'), ('OSverStr', 'O'), ('OSname', 'O')])]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [hpaulj's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723802/scipy-and-preserving-mat-file-mat-matlab-data-file-structure#comment53295509_32723802) it appears you may be looking for

```
aa = np.empty((1,1), dtype='O')
aa[0,0] = np.array([[ ([[15]], [], [u'5.0.1'], [u'Android'], [u'main'], [u'MSM8960'])]], 
          dtype=[('OSversInt', 'O'), ('Desc', 'O'), ('OSversStr', 'O'),
                 ('OSname', 'O'), ('platform', 'O'), ('Board', 'O')])
```

which yields

```
In [39]: aa
Out[39]: 
array([[ array([[([[15]], [], [u'5.0.1'], [u'Android'], [u'main'], [u'MSM8960'])]], 
      dtype=[('OSversInt', 'O'), ('Desc', 'O'), ('OSversStr', 'O'), ('OSname', 'O'), ('platform', 'O'), ('Board', 'O')])]], dtype=object)
```

---

When you want to place an arbitrary Python object (such as a NumPy array or a list) inside of a NumPy array, the dtype must be `object`. In this case construction with `np.array` fails because this function [interprets inner sequences](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2011-September/058390.html) (other than tuples) as values to be recursed upon instead of as atomic elements.

So the trick to creating these nested object arrays is to create the outer object array first:

```
aa = np.empty((1,1), dtype='O')
```

and then at *assign* the desired value to the cells of the array:

```
aa[0,0] = ...
```

Note that nested NumPy arrays of dtype `object` do not allow you to take
advantage of NumPy's fast (mainly numeric) functions. They have essentially the
same memory footprint as the Python objects they contain, and performance-wise
they are typically no better than plain Python lists of lists.

Comment: I'd have to check, but I think `loadmat` loads MATLAB structures or cells as object arrays.