# Loading a Cell Array (.mat file) into Python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, scipy, mat

I have a 25x4x3 Cell Array which I have saved into a .mat file and now need to load into Python.

A simple .mat file I am familiar with, but being new to Python, this problem is a little over my head. The 25 dimensions and 4 dimensions represent integers that I need to call later in my code. The 3 dimension in the cell array contains a list of datetime arrays, data, and then more character arrays of labels for that data.

e.g. (**pseudocode**)

```matlab
.mat(1,1,1) = datetime arrays; 
.mat(1,1,2) = data corresponding to datetime arrays; 
.mat(1,1,3) = labels for each column in that data.
```

Obviously I need to load this into Python with `loadmat('.mat')` and then I get confused because my variable explorer does not show the .mat file. I have no idea how to pick apart the contents to correctly convert `datettime` indices accordingly, numbers to floats, etc.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Right now I simply have:

```py
filemat = 'Pdata.mat'
Pdata = sio.loadmat(filemat)
```

It is loading the .mat as an object from what I can tell.

Comment: `Pdata` should be a dictionary, `Pdata['mat']` should be the object encoding your `mat` cell.  Because it comes from a `cell` with mixed data, it won't be a simple `numpy` numeric array.  Previous `loadmat` questions have demonstrated how to extract information from such structures (see the side bar).  You may have to show us the variable (if it's not too big).

Comment: My last answer along this line: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42258001/901925; or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723802/scipy-and-preserving-mat-file-mat-matlab-data-file-structure

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there.

First let me build some sample matlab data:

```
a = num2cell(rand(25,4,3));
a{13} = 'abc';
save('/tmp/tmp4Python.mat','a')
```

Now load it in Python

```
import scipy.io
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('/tmp/tmp4Python.mat')
```

And assign the variable

```
a = mat['a']
```

Now if we want to access the `'abc'` string we do it as follows (note that Python indexing starts at 0, whereas MATLAB indexing starts at 1):

```
a[12][0][0]
```

Comment: how do you deal with it if it is a file save using format v7.3?

Comment: @Tulkkas In that case, you can `import hdf5storage` then `hdf5storage.loadmat(file.mat)`

Answer (score 0):

How about assigning a variable that **only contains a ranged value of 'a'?** is it possible like this?

```
x1 = mat['a', range(1, 20, 1)]
```