# Convert loaded mat file back to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, spyder

I save images in numpy array of size 5000,96,96 into .mat file using `scipy.io.savemat()`.

When I want to load back these images into Python I use `scipy.io.loadmat()`, however, this time they are put into dictionary.

How can I neatly put them from Dictionary to NumPy array?

I am using the `scipy.io.loadmat` to load matlab file and want to put it in NumPy array. The images are of dims = (5000,96,96)

```
scipy.io.savemat("images.mat")
z = scipy.io.loadmat("images.mat")
```

images in NumPy array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python dict to numpy structured array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579649/python-dict-to-numpy-structured-array)

Comment: Just use python dictionary indexing,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save a 3d array:

```
In [53]: from scipy import io                                                   
In [54]: arr = np.arange(8*3*3).reshape(8,3,3)                                  
In [56]: io.savemat('threed.mat',{"a":arr})
```

Load it:

```
In [57]: dat = io.loadmat('threed.mat')                                         
In [58]: list(dat.keys())                                                       
Out[58]: ['__header__', '__version__', '__globals__', 'a']
```

Access array by key (normal dictionary action):

```
In [59]: dat['a'].shape                                                         
Out[59]: (8, 3, 3)
In [61]: np.allclose(arr,dat['a'])                                              
Out[61]: True
```

Answer (score -1):

According to this post:
[python dict to numpy structured array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579649/python-dict-to-numpy-structured-array)

Coverting a dictionary to a numpy array can be done as follow:

```
import numpy as np
result = {0: 1.1, 1: 0.7, 2: 0.9, 3: 0.5, 4: 1.0, 5: 0.8, 6: 0.3}

names = ['id','value']
formats = ['int','float']
dtype = dict(names = names, formats=formats)
array = np.array(list(result.items()), dtype=dtype)

print(repr(array))
```

This leads to the following result:

```
array([(0, 1.1), (1, 0.7), (2, 0.9), (3, 0.5), (4, 1. ), (5, 0.8),
       (6, 0.3)], dtype=[('id', '<i4'), ('value', '<f8')])
```

Do you have an example of a dictionary entry you are trying to convert?

Comment: He doesn't need a structured array.

Comment: This doesn't relate to the question at all. You've invented the problem and then solved it.