# Fastest way to import JSON formated string to numpy.recarray?

Tags: python, json, numpy

Consider this JSON formatted string:

```
json_string = '{"SYM": ["this_string","this_string","this_string"],"DATE": ["NaN","NaN","NaN"],"YEST": ["NaN","NaN","NaN"],"other_DATE": ["NaN","NaN","NaN"],"SIZE": ["NaN","NaN","NaN"],"ACTIVITY": ["2019-09-27 14:18:28.000700 UTC","2019-09-27 14:18:28.000700 UTC","2019-09-27 14:18:28.000600 UTC"]}'
```

I can import it to numpy.recarray doing [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15579807/189035) operations:

```
result      = ast.literal_eval(json_string)
names       = list(result.keys())
formats     = ['O'] * len(names)
dtype       = dict(names = names, formats=formats)
array       = numpy.array(result.items(), dtype=dtype)
```

This seems a lot of hops. Is there a faster way?

Comment: How about `numpy.array(json.loads(json_string).items(), dtype=dtype)`? literal_eval will fail for something like `{"FOO": [null, NaN]}` while the json module will correctly load it as `{u'FOO': [None, nan]}`

Comment: Perfect in my case, as I dtype is pre-set. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you extract `names` and `formats` if you don't use them?  `json_string` evaluates as a dictionary.  Structured array `data` is supposed to be a list of tuples, where the tuples match the `dtype`.  There isn't any special `json` processing in `numpy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need the second and third steps, and you can condensate the first and last in the same line:

```
array = numpy.array(ast.literal_eval(json_string).items(), dtype=dtype)
```

That said, I would use the `json` module instead of `ast.literal_eval` because `literal_eval` will fail for valid JSON like `{"FOO": [null, NaN]}`.

```
import json
numpy.array(json.loads(json_string).items(), dtype=dtype)
```

Comment: I also prefer your json-based solution to the `ast.literal_eval` one (my choice of the latter was guided by ignorance, not anything specific about the problem at hand).